# asp.net mvc 4. 0 - multiple action to render data to same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How i can overload actions in a controller.

```
public ActionResult OnlineHome()
        {
            OnlineDataModel dm = new OnlineDataModel();
            dm.CatagoryData = new List<category>();
            dm.ProductData = new List<product>();
            dm.CatagoryData = db.categories.ToList();
            return View(dm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OnlineHome(int CategoryId)
        {
            OnlineDataModel dm = new OnlineDataModel();
            dm.CatagoryData = new List<category>();
            dm.ProductData = new List<product>();

            dm.CatagoryData = db.categories.ToList();
            Convert.ToInt32(CategoryId) select p).ToList() ;
            var data= db.products.Where(d => d.CategoryID == CategoryId).ToList();
            dm.ProductData = data.ToList();
            ViewBag.data = data;
            return View(dm);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OnlineHome(OnlineDataModel data)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

please help. how i can overload the actions which will render data to same view

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ActionName attribute if you want your code to do overloading.

```
[ActionName("MyOverloadedName")]
```

To Render the Same View, You can pass the Model and ViewName like this.

```
return View("ViewName",model);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can provide **ActionName** attribute with different name while calling it from View. Like

```
[ActionName("OnlineHomeWithCategoryId")]
public ActionResult OnlineHome(int CategoryId)
{
}

[ActionName("OnlineHomeWithData")]
public ActionResult OnlineHome(OnlineDataModel data)
{
}
```

Now you just need to use these action names while calling these action metho

Comment: According to the ActionName attribute, You have to change your View name also.